# Roboform keeps popping up for feedback after I've uninstalled it

Tags: windows, website, adware, roboform

Roboform keeps popping up [a window](http://roboform.com/uninstall.html?aaa=KICMJMNMJJOMMMNJKJOMCNMMLMLMJJCNLMJMGMPMCNHMMJLJNMCNNMLJPMKMJMLJGMKMMJNMNMMJJNJICMIMCNGMCNMMFMOMOMCNIMOMGMCNOMHMMMJMNMFMJMCNMMCNGMJMPMPMCNNMJNPICMPMFMFMNMPMLMJNHICMEKMICNJJCKJNBJCMOJOJNIAJBJJNKJCMJNNICMJNDJCMKJBJJNMJCMPMFMPMFMPMJNFICMNIJJIIGJPIKJAJKILIBNKJHIKJ) asking for feedback after I've uninstalled it on windows 10. It has popped up so much time already that my browser(microsoft edge chromium) autocompletes it after I enter `roboform` in my address bar. I've entered some stuff in the feedback box at least fifteen times. How do I stop it?

EDIT: It seems like it pops up whenever I press the windows key.

EDIT 2: I have searched my entire appdata folder, deleted an empty "Roboform" and "Siber Systems"(The Manufacturer) folder, and the problem still persists.

Comment: You've uninstalled the program itself, maybe not the extensions it (probably) installs in your browsers too. Can you check?

Comment: I already uninstalled the extensions.

Comment: If I were you, I'd do the following: Go to the Roboform website (https://www.roboform.com/fr/) and download the newest version; install it again; download and install Revo Uninstaller Free (here: https://www.revouninstaller.com/fr/revo-uninstaller-free-download/); run Revo, and proceed to uninstall Roboform in Advanced user mode (in the window with the Scan button, before scanning for leftovers, choose Advanced); delete all the pre-checked files, folders and registry entry Revo will point you at; restart your PC.

Comment: Um I checked for leftovers using CleanMyPC. CleanMyPC also has a handy uninstaller.

Comment: We all have our favorite tools to play with, I guess. If you trust this one, then it's fine by me. One thing you could do if the page keep popping up is check your registry for traces of "roboform" and delete the corresponding keys and values.

Comment: I've looked in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` and no traces of roboform or the manufacturer Siber Systems.

Comment: Have you checked in your browsers' preferences if Roboform hadn't overwritten your homepage settings somehow? Or in Control Panel > Internet options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106638/discussion-between-aaron-and-didier).